# Error while executing shell script of copiying a directory in ruby if the directory is having a space in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rubygems

Lets say I have a directory with name 'test folder' and when I tried to make a copy of it using ruby script it threw an error.

Here is what I tried:

> irb(main):001:0>`` `cp -R test\ folder folder` ``

Output:

> `usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file
>   target_file
>          cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
>   => ""`

Comment: Try cp -R test\ folder/ folder/

Comment: Again same output.
irb(main):020:0> `` `cp -R test\ folder folder/` ``
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
=> ""

Comment: ok. same erro. Does **test folder** is in the same directory as the **folder** ?

Comment: Yes. Refer the answer given by BoraMa down. It worked. Anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: I also learned. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the folder name in apostrophes should work for you:

```
`cp -R 'test folder' folder`
```

But a more ruby-style method would be to use [`FileUtils.cp_r`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/FileUtils/cp_r/class):

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp_r 'test folder', 'folder'
```

Both of these methods will copy the `test folder` **into** the `folder` so there will be a `test folder` subdirectory created under `folder`. If you want to copy *the contents* of the `test folder` only, use `'test folder/.'` instead of `'test folder'` in the commands.